# What does putting a constraint in an argument's type instead of function's type do?

Tags: haskell

I put a constraint in the type of a function's argument instead of putting in the function's type.
I thought this would either give a syntax error or add more information to the type of the function.
But it looks like the constraint is completely ignored.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

test :: a -> String
test (n :: (Num a, Ord a) => a) =
    if n > 10 then "Hello"
    else "World"

main = print "Hello World"
```

This gives the following type error:

```hs
Test3.hs:6:8: error:
    • No instance for (Num a) arising from a use of ‘n’
      Possible fix:
        add (Num a) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            test :: forall a. a -> String
    • In the first argument of ‘(>)’, namely ‘n’
      In the expression: n > 10
      In the expression: if n > 10 then "Hello" else "World"
  |
6 |     if n > 10 then "Hello"
  |        ^

Test3.hs:6:8: error:
    • No instance for (Ord a) arising from a use of ‘>’
      Possible fix:
        add (Ord a) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            test :: forall a. a -> String
    • In the expression: n > 10
      In the expression: if n > 10 then "Hello" else "World"
      In an equation for ‘test’:
          test (n :: (Num a, Ord a) => a)
            = if n > 10 then "Hello" else "World"
  |
6 |     if n > 10 then "Hello"
  |
```

What does putting a constraint in the the argument's type actually do?

EDIT:

Why does this need `RankNTypes` extension?
It is not needed if I remove `(Num a, Ord a) =>` constraint.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209192/discussion-on-question-by-happycoder97-what-does-putting-a-constraint-in-an-argu).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a rather exotic instance of polymorphic subsumption, as [described here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/putting.pdf), interacting with constraint subsumption.

If a type `a` subsumes `b`, then `exp :: a` implies `exp :: b` in the surface language. A particular example of subsumption is that `f :: forall a. a -> a` implies `f :: Int -> Int`. Also, we have `n :: Int` implies `n :: c => Int` for any `c` constraint.

However, in the core language there is no subsumption at all. Every case of subsumption in the surface language must be translated to explicit lambdas and applications. Also, `c => a` simply becomes `c -> a`, and usage of constrained functions is translated to simple function application of `f :: c => a` to some `inst :: c`. Hence, `f :: forall a. a -> a` becomes `f @Int :: Int -> Int`, and
`n :: Int` becomes `\_ -> n :: c -> Int`.

A rarely used case is the contravariant subsumption rule for functions. The following is valid code:

```
f :: (Int -> Int) -> Bool
f _ = True

g :: (forall a. a -> a) -> Bool
g = f
```

This is translated to

```
f :: (Int -> Int) -> Bool
f = \_ -> True

g :: (forall a. a -> a) -> Bool
g = \x -> f (x @Int)
```

It works similarly with constraint subsumption:

```
f :: forall a. (Eq a => a) -> Bool
f _ = True

g :: forall a . a -> Bool
g = f
```

Which is translated to

```
f :: forall a. (Eq a -> a) -> Bool
f = \_ -> True

g :: forall a . a -> Bool
g = \x -> f (\_ -> x)
```

Getting closer to the original question, if we have

```
f (x :: Eq a => a) = True
```

as a top definition, its inferred type is `forall a. (Eq a => a) -> Bool`. However, we can have any type annotation for `f` which is subsumed by the inferred type! So we may have:

```
f :: forall a. a -> Bool
f (x :: Eq a => a) = True
```

And GHC is still happy. The original code

```
test :: a -> String
test (n :: (Num a, Ord a) => a) =
    if n > 10 then "Hello"
    else "World"
```

is equivalent to the slightly clearer following version:

```
test :: forall a. a -> String
test (n :: (Num a, Ord a) => a) =
    if n > 10 then "Hello"
    else "World"
```

The type error which you get is simply because `n` is really a function with two arguments, one has type `Num a` and the other `Ord a`, and both of these arguments
are records containing `Num` and `Ord` methods. However, since there are no such instances in scope in the definition, you cannot use `n` as a number. The translation would convert `n > 10` to `(>) inst (n inst) (10 inst)`, where `inst :: Num a`, but there is no such `inst`, so we cannot translate.

Hence, in the body of `test` the code is still checked with `n :: (Num a, Ord a) => a)`. However, if we just return "Hello" without using `n`, then similarly to the previous `f` case, we get an inferred type which subsumes the `forall a. a -> String` annotation type. The subsumption is then realized in the translation output by replacing every occurrence of `n` in the body of `test` with `\_ -> n`. But since `n` does not occur in the body, the translation does not do anything here.